# Retrieve list of all great great grandchildren of a set id

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying loop through all pages which are a great great grandchild of the id of 101, but I can't get this to work. Any suggestions to what the problem might be?

```
    $args = array(
                'post_type'   => 'page',
                'page_id' =>  $greatGreatGrandChild-of-101, ?
                'posts_per_page' => -1
         );
```

Comment: How are you selecting which great great grandchild you want? There must be some more code that loop through the great grandchildren where you can access an ID.

Comment: Perhaps [get_page_children()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it this way in the end. This lists all great great grandchildren or the page with an id 101.

```
    <ul>

        <?php
        $postid = 101;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $postid
            );
        $child_level = get_posts($args);

        if($child_level) :
            foreach($child_level as $child_page) :

                $chgs = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_parent' => $child_page->ID
                    );
            $grandchild_level = get_posts( $chgs );

            if($grandchild_level) :
                foreach($grandchild_level as $grandchild_level) :

                    $grgs = array(
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'orderby' => 'rand',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_parent' => $grandchild_level->ID
                        );
                $greatgrandchild_level = get_posts( $grgs );

                if($greatgrandchild_level) :
                    foreach ($greatgrandchild_level as $greatgrandchild_level) :

                        $ggrgs = array(
                            'post_type' => 'page',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'orderby' => 'rand',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_parent' => $greatgrandchild_level->ID
                            );
                    $greatgreatgrandchild_level = get_posts( $ggrgs );


                    $my_query = new WP_Query($ggrgs);
                    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>



                    <?php endwhile;
                }
                wp_reset_query();

                endforeach;
                endif;

                endforeach;
                endif;

                endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>

            </ul>
```